# How to get taxation feature on token transactions on uniswap?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, fees

I have an ERC20 token contract deployed on mainnet.

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity <=0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";

contract Goofy is ERC20, ERC20Burnable {
constructor() ERC20("Buff Goofy", "BFGY") {
_mint(msg.sender, 1000000000000000*10**18);
}
}

I have on the process of presale of the token via pinksale.

I do have a separate contract to handle buy-token on my website. The code is :

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Goofymarket is Ownable {

```
IERC20 public token;
uint256 public tokenPrice;
address public tokenOwner;


uint256 public taxToMktwalletPercentage;
uint256 public taxToLiquidityPercentage;

address public marketWallet;
uint256 public marketWalletInitial;

address public liquidityWallet;

address public developerWallet;
uint256 public developerWalletTransfer;

constructor(address goofytoken,uint tokenprice,uint taxToLiquiditypercentage,uint taxToMktwalletPercntage,uint marketWalletInitialPercentage,uint developerWalletPercentage, address mktwallet, address liquidtywallet,address developerwallet) {
    token = IERC20(goofytoken);
    tokenOwner=msg.sender;
    tokenPrice=tokenprice;
    marketWalletInitial=token.totalSupply()*marketWalletInitialPercentage/100;
    developerWalletTransfer=token.totalSupply()*developerWalletPercentage/100;
    taxToLiquidityPercentage=taxToLiquiditypercentage;
    taxToMktwalletPercentage=taxToMktwalletPercntage;
    marketWallet=mktwallet;
    liquidityWallet=liquidtywallet;
    developerWallet=developerwallet;
}

  
function initialTransferToWallets() external onlyOwner {
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, marketWallet,marketWalletInitial);
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender,developerWallet, developerWalletTransfer);
}


function refillMarketWallet(uint amount) external onlyOwner {
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, marketWallet,amount);
}

function changeTax(uint mktwallettax, uint liquidityTax) external onlyOwner {
    require(mktwallettax+liquidityTax<=5,"Total Tax cant be more than 5%");
    taxToLiquidityPercentage=mktwallettax;
    taxToMktwalletPercentage=liquidityTax;        
}


function buyToken() external payable {

    uint equivalentTokens=msg.value*10**18/tokenPrice;
    uint taxOnValue=taxToMktwalletPercentage* msg.value/100;
    payable(marketWallet).transfer(taxOnValue);
    
    uint taxOnTokens=taxToLiquidityPercentage*equivalentTokens/100;
    uint tokenAfterTax=equivalentTokens-taxOnTokens;
    require(tokenAfterTax<=token.balanceOf(marketWallet),"Ask owner to refill marketting wallet");
    
    token.transferFrom(marketWallet,msg.sender, tokenAfterTax);
    token.transferFrom(tokenOwner,liquidityWallet,taxOnTokens);
}




receive() external payable {}

function withdrawEther(address recipent, uint amount) external onlyOwner {
    payable(recipent).transfer(amount);
}
```

}

---

After that I want to list the token on uniswap. Once, on uniswap, how do I setup that every transaction of my token (buy/ sale) gives me a tax of 5% just like I did on the above smart contract.

Do I need to make a separate smart contract for this? Or I can link the same contract to uniswap?

Can someone guide please.

Comment: [For more information on token tax and some pointers to get started. see this article](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/transfer-fees-token-taxes-and-honeypots).

Comment: Have the same question, want to tax token sales/buys. It's straight forward if you sell from your custom contract. But I need a workaround Uniswap pool!